# Reversal of primary comparison operators (==, <=>) in C++20

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

From what I understand, the C++20 standard allows the compiler to automatically call the reversed comparison operator for `==` and `<=>` when the operator for the direction used in code is missing but the reversed operator exists. Like in [this](https://godbolt.org/z/vd7PWcvYY) example:

```
struct A {
    constexpr A() = default;
};

struct B
{
    constexpr bool operator==(A const& other) const {
        return true;
    }
};

static_assert(B{} == A{}); // This is defined
static_assert(A{} == B{}); // Fails in C++17, automatically generated in C++20
```

I looked at the [[class.compare]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.compare) section of the standard but I fail to find where it is stated.

Can someone please point the exact place in the standard?

Comment: They're not actually generated, but *called* when you use the reverse notation. This is probably described near "overload resolution".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Indeed, that's seen from the disassembly! Thanks, I'll edit the question

Comment: @vvv444 And because there isn't actually anything generated for the class, you don't need to look into [class]. Instead you need to look into [over] since only overload resolution is affected.

Comment: What is the reverse of operator `<=>`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Actually I'm not sure. Can I define `<=>` between two different types? Like this `bool B::operator<=>(A const& other) const`?

Comment: @vvv444 your title mentioned reverse of `<=>`, so I am curious.  I have never heard of a reverse of operator `<=>`, but I haven't used that operator.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Actually, https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match#oper-3.4.2 talks about `<=>` reversal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match#oper-3.4.4

I think it is in:

Overload resolution/operators in expressions

[over.match.oper]

> For the equality operators, the rewritten candidates also include a
> synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed,
> for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression y == x.